# Accessing prototype cell defined in UITableViewController in storyboard for instantiation of that class in code

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a UITableViewController with a single prototype cell defined in my storyboard.  I have created a subclass of UITableViewController for this, and I wish to instantiate a new instance of this from code.  I've done this with:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    MyTableViewController *mtvc = [[MyTableViewController alloc] init];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:mtvc animated:YES];
}
```

I am getting an exception when I select a row to bring up the new table view, *"unable to dequeue a cell with identifier MyIdentifier - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard"*.

I presume that this is because the prototype cell is defined in the storyboard and not in my code.  Is there a correct way to define the prototype cell in my code instead so that I can access it when I instantiate an instance of MyTableViewController in code?  Or is there a way to access the definition in the storyboard?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I understand, I think instead of

`MyTableViewController *mtvc = [[MyTableViewController alloc] init];`

you should try instantiating the table view controller using the storyboard method

`– instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:`

In this, your table view controller has no chance of knowing about the prototype cell defined in your storyboard.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! That works really nicely.  I was hoping you could do something like that, but I hadn't been able to find the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If your cell is a prototype cell in a storyboard you should not check if the cell=nil and then if it is create one. You just have to dequeue a cell with the reuse identifier (add the reuseIdentifier in your storyboard prototype cell too). All these is done in the 
`cellForRowAtIndexPath` delegate method and not the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` you've posted. There is your problem.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    MyCustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MyCustomCell"];
    return cell*
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be better to create a push segue in the storyboard and call `[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Segue Identifier"]`

And if you have the `cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath` method defined in `MyTableViewController.m` and you initialize the cell like so:

`MyCustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"My Identifier"]`

It should work.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help, everyone.  I managed to get it working.  I ended up subclassing UITableCell and defining my prototype cell there.  I then register the class in viewDidLoad for MyTableViewController, like this:

```
[self.tableView registerClass:[MyTableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"MyIdentifier"];
```